# ChargeBee Drop-in checkout + React: Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chargebee

I'm trying to add the drop-in checkout to a react SPA, following https://www.chargebee.com/checkout-portal-docs/drop-in-tutorial.html#implementation. I'm dynamically adding `chargebee.js` after the rest of the view gets rendered, and then call `registerAgain()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const el = document.createElement('script');
    el.onload = () => {
        window.Chargebee.registerAgain();
        // this.setState({ chargebeeReady: true });
    };
    el.setAttribute('data-cb-site', 'derp-test');
    el.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}

render() {
    // [...]
    <a
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        data-cb-type="checkout"
        data-cb-plan-id="asdf-test"
    >
        Subscribe
    </a>
    // [...]
}
```

when clicking `subscribe` I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCart' of null
    at t.a (event-binding.ts:24)
    at Function.value (chargebee.ts:46)
    at HTMLScriptElement.el.onload (Subscribe.js:23)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chargebee instance will be created when DOMContentLoaded event is triggered.Since, you are loading it asynchronously, instance is not getting created. So you can create the instance using Chargebee.init().

```
componentDidMount() {
    const el = document.createElement('script');
    el.onload = () => {
      window.Chargebee.init({
        "site": "derp-test"
      });
      window.Chargebee.registerAgain();
      // this.setState({ chargebeeReady: true });
    };
    el.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: I am going with this implementation and I am getting this error in the console:
{message: "Sorry, we couldn't find the site mysite-test"}. 
Any Idea what this might be? Should I set up anything extra in my Chargebee site ?

Comment: faces the same issue ( 4 years ago omg). In my case - chargebee script for some reason creates a link with chargebeestatic.com instead chargebee.com. With chargebee.com everything works fine. But how can i fix this still unknown

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js"></script>

<script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
     Chargebee.init({
          site: "site_name", // your test site
          publishableKey: "test_"
          })
      Chargebee.registerAgain();

})
    
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).